# Can an instance variable be treated as an array in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here I am getting values from my model and I am putting it as an instance variable in my controller:

```
@users = User.where(:approved => true, :enabled => true)
```

now I want `@users` to behave as an array so that I can perform the following operation:

```
@users = @users | current_user
```

i.e an array union. any pointers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this would initialize the `@current_user` array:

```
@current_user = [current_user]
```

then I did

```
@users = @current_user | @users
```

and it worked!

Please suggest if you have a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
@users = User.where(:approved => true, :enabled => true).to_a
```